# Service Bus in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, azureservicebus

I would like my ASP.NET Core application to send messages to a Azure Service Bus.

In Microsoft's article [Best Practices for performance improvements using Service Bus Messaging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-performance-improvements) they argue that you should re-use instances of clients.

> It is recommended that you do not close messaging factories or queue, topic, and subscription clients after you send a message, and then re-create them when you send the next message.

So I take that as I should not instantiate a new instance of the client ([`TopicClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.servicebus.topicclient?view=azure-dotnet) or [`QueueClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.servicebus.queueclient?view=azure-dotnet)) inside my controller using the `new` keyword.

I guess that I should use [dependency injection in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection).

Should I directly inject a `TopicClient`/`QueueClient` or should I create an own class that wraps an instance of the client and expose a `SendAsync` method?

When registering the service with dependency injector should I register it as a singleton?

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55546270). Confirmation that the [clients are threadsafe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51415295).

Comment: @StuartLC What does this mean in the context of my question?

Comment: With each of the clients each you need to specify which queue or topic you intend communicating with, which can make it messy to inject the correct client instance into the correct injection site. So if you have multiple topics / queues, you can consider building your own wrapper which creates and caches the respective client instances. And the Azure clients are threadsafe, so there's no need to manage contention around them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We did it with a wrapper class that is then returning the TopicClient/QueueClient and registered it as a singleton and found no big issues with this approach.

We based our approach on this example provided by Microsoft [eshopOnContainers](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers).

The example code for this functionality is found in this [file](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers/blob/dev/src/BuildingBlocks/EventBus/EventBusServiceBus/DefaultServiceBusPersisterConnection.cs). They than register this class as singleton in Startup.cs in the services where they require ServiceBus.

Comment: How does your code look like? It is a bit confusing that the method is named `CreateModel`. But then that is not what is used in the controllers, it is part of `EventBusServiceBus` which is used in controllers by `IEventBus` which looks like it violates the interface segregation policy.

Comment: We have abstraction for `IEventBus` and the `EventBusServiceBus` is a service Bus implementation of it. For this class to work correctly you have to provide it implementation of `IAzureServiceBusProvider` (here we have `CreateTopicClient` and `CreateQueueClient` methods) in the constructor.
We then register `AzureServiceBusProvider` as a singleton to make sure that the clients are not closed by our code. With the DI this `AzureServiceBusProvider` is injected into `IServiceBusPersisterConnection`. There is no violation as these interfaces are all connected to Service Bus implementation